# Finding multiple criteria with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have a user form has 2 textboxes named "date" and "shift" and button to trigger a code. also a have a excel file named data.xlsx has "sheet1" have A column dates added as 07/02/2017, B column shift added as A/B/C.

```
date.value = "07/02/2017"
shift.value = "C"
```

so what i want to do is to find the row number of A column contains "07/02/2017" and B column contains "C" in data.xlsx.

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? provide your work in progress.

Comment: What about using `MATCH()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to find the Shift row in Column B (using the `Match` function).

You should be able to make the modifications to make it work also for finding the date from `date` `TextBox`.

**Code**

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' this code goes inside the command button (inside the User_Form module)
Dim ValToSearch
Dim MatchRes As Variant

ValToSearch = Me.shift.Value '<-- get the value to look for

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MatchRes = Application.Match(ValToSearch, .Range("B:B"), 0)
    If IsError(MatchRes) Then '<-- match not found
        MsgBox "Not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Found at row " & MatchRes
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but what i see that you have only found shift.value in B column. what about date.value in A column. i need to find both same time.

Comment: @MahmutUzun  I have u the concept, in sure u can make the minimal effort to adapt the other case

Comment: i have come this far by using "if" and chechking other column. but it couses another problems. thanks for answer.